# How can I make my script run on multiple sheets on Google Sheets ? I'm inserting rows with data and need it to run on multiple sheets

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script that inserts a row below row 1 of each sheet and includes some data in that row. It works for the first sheet, but I need it to run for multiple sheets. Each sheet is a business manager's name (Brian, for example), and it would be helpful to have this run for all sheets. I have tried several methods from previous similar questions but have not gotten anything to work. The code is below.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSht = ss.getSheetByName("Brian");
  var lastRow = dataSht.insertRows(2,1)
  var dataRng = dataSht.getRange("A2:D2").getValues();
  dataSht.getRange("A2:B2").setFormula('=A3:B3')
}
```

Comment: instead of .getSheetByName() use .getSheets() and then iterate through the resulting array of sheets

Comment: Welcome to [so]. You should spend some time learning the basics about Google Apps Script and JavaScript. Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, show what you have tried to achieve your goal to find similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheets().forEach(function(dataSht){
    dataSht.insertRows(2,1)
    dataSht.getRange("A2:B2").setFormula('=A3:B3')
  })
}
```

Comment: By the way you can use: `dataSht =>` instead of `function(dataSht)`. It's about the same but less typing.

Comment: thanks for the tip. would you keep .forEach or get rid of it in its entirety?

Answer (score 2):

#### If you don't wish to use all sheets

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const incl = ["Brian", "others"]
  ss.getSheets().filter(s => ~incl.indexOf(s.getName())).forEach(sh => {
    sh.insertRows(2, 1)
    sh.getRange("A2:B2").setFormula('=A3:B3')
  })
}
```

Comment: I did this but it didn't work. should I use "others" literally or type out the name of each sheet?

Comment: What do you think?